# how to achieve re usability of method in TestNG

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng, appium-android

package com.testng.learn;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidKeyCode;

public class First {

```
AndroidDriver driver;<br/>
DesiredCapabilities caps;<br/>

@BeforeTest<br/>
public void DC() {<br/>
    try {<br/>
        // Set the Desired Capabilities<br/>
        caps = new DesiredCapabilities();<br/>
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");<br/>
        caps.setCapability("udid", "LGM70021d764e8"); // Give Device ID of your mobile phone<br/>
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");<br/>
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");<br/>
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.contacts");<br/>
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.contacts.activities.DialtactsActivity");<br/>
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");<br/>
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);<br/>
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {<br/>
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block<br/>
        e.printStackTrace();<br/>
```

}
    }

```
@DataProvider()<br/>
public void scroll(String text) {<br/>
    try {<br/>
        System.out.println(text);<br/>
        driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
                "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(" + "new UiSelector().text(\"" + text + "\"));"))
                .click();<br/>

        Thread.sleep(5000);<br/>
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {<br/>
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block<br/>
        e.printStackTrace();<br/>
    }<br/>
}<br/>

@Test(priority = 0)<br/>
public void print() {<br/>
    try {<br/>

        String text = "Karthik";<br/>
        Thread.sleep(2000);<br/>
        driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Contacts Tab 3 of 4").click();<br/>
        Thread.sleep(1000);<br/>

        First f1 = new First();<br/>
        f1.scroll(text);<br/>

        Thread.sleep(1000);<br/>
        driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);<br/>
        Thread.sleep(2000);<br/>
        driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME);<br/>

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {<br/>
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block<br/>
        e.printStackTrace();<br/>
    }<br/>

}<br/>
```

}

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: @IshitaShah I want to call "public void scroll(String text) " from "public void print()" but it is throwing null pointer exception error

Comment: Firstly, As according to your code, You have define @DataProvider() method incorrectly. You should need to refer articles on TestNG Dataprovider.

Comment: Thank you I checked as you said I works fine now.

Comment: Please accept answer, Other user might not check comments, Reader are mostly refer Accepted answer. So please accept answer, if you think it has solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As according to your code, You have define `@DataProvider()` method incorrectly. You should need to refer articles on `TestNG Dataprovider`.